# Is there any way to enable or disable the Spring bean definition in applicationContext.xml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there any way to **enable** or **disable** a java bean definition in application context?

```
<bean id="enBean" classs="com.en.bean.BeanName">
   <property name="prop1"/>
</bean>
```

Or, is there any way to load the bean **conditionally** defined in application context?

Answer (score 11):

There is a new feature [`@Profile`](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) in spring 3.1 that would do the job

From [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/10/spring-3.1-rc1-release)

> Spring 3.1 introduces the concept of environment profiles. A common
>   use case is the setting up of beans that are different between
>   development, QA and production environments. A typical example is
>   going against a standalone DataSource in development versus looking up
>   the DataSource from JNDI in production. Another example is a beans
>   profile for profiling that can easily be turned on or off. You can add
>   a profile attribute on a beans element in XML or add @Profile
>   annotation in code. Note that a Spring bean can be assigned to
>   multiple profiles.

```
<beans profile="dev">
    ...
</beans>
@Profile("dev")
public class Bean {
    ...
}
```

> These profiles can be activated through the spring.profiles.active
>   property which may be specified through an environment variable, a JVM
>   system property, a Servlet  in web.xml or JNDI. These
>   profiles can also be activated through code using
>   Environment.setActiveProfiles(String ...). To make bean profiles work,
>   nested beans elements are now allowed in the Spring XML, although
>   constrained only at the end of the file. Note that it's recommended to
>   keep your bean topology as close as possible between environments, so
>   your application gets properly tested across environments. You also
>   use the Environment.containsProperty() method to search for properties
>   across the different property sources. This property resolution also
>   works for ${placeholder} variables in XML bean definitions.

Comment: If this is the use case then follow or just comment it out as @Skaffman said