# Making a spring bean dynamically refer to two classes based on a system property in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to achieve the below functionality using Spring but have not succeeded till now.

Create a spring bean "testBean" in XML file and dynamically point it to class "A" or "B" depending on whether some system property "C" has been set or not. I want to handle this at the XML configuration file level itself. The rest of the application should be able to use the bean "testBean" seamlessly.

Please let me know how can this be done using Spring? Let me know if any other details are required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [bean profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) to achieve this

**Also See**

- [is-there-any-way-to-enable-or-disable-the-spring-bean-definition-in-applicationcation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279270/is-there-any-way-to-enable-or-disable-the-spring-bean-definition-in-applicationc)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I realized that either using bean profiles(http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) or the unified property management(http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/) feature of Spring 3.1 I can achieve this. The issue is that we are still using Spring 3.0 . Could you suggest me some solution for the same with Spring 3.0 ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the expression language to configure your testBean like this (not tested):

```
<bean id="testBean" class="com.test.TestBean">
    <property name="pointer" value="#{ systemProperties['C'] != null ? 'com.test.A' : 'com.test.B' }"/>
</bean>
```

See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html) for further reference.

Relevant parts:

- 6.4.1 XML based configuration
- 6.5.13 Ternary Operator (If-Then-Else)

Comment: I don't need to set some property of a bean using PropertyPlaceHolders. I need to dynamically switch the class to which the bean points to based on some property. I doubt if this approach would work for my problem. Thanks for your suggestion though.