# placeholder not found when using an alias to swap out beans

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, alias

as a follow up to [this post about bean aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124982/how-to-set-the-dynamically-a-bean-reference-in-spring)

I am trying to do something similar to the above post with a an alias for purposes of swapping a bean reference using a property (literally with the same purpose in mind as above post).

However, when I try it I get
Caused by: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'crypto.provider'**

if I use a delegate to pass this same placeholder in as a constructor parameter it works fine. Below is the code

```
#property file
crypto.provider = safenet
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans>
    <alias name="${crypto.provider}" alias="defaultProvider" />
</beans>
```

classes:

```
@Component ("caesar")
public class CaesarCipherEncryptionProvider implements EncryptionProvider{
//implementation here
}

@Component ("safenet")
public class SafenetEncryptionProvider implements EncryptionProvider{
//implementation here
}
```

The Test case

```
public class SafeNetEncryptionProviderTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("defaultProvider") // note: Intellij can't find this bean
    private EncryptionProvider provider;

    @Test
    public void testEncryptDecrypt() throws Exception{
        String plaintext = "every.other.email.address.is.shorter.than.this.email.address" +
                "@long-email-addresses-incorporated.home-of-the-extra-long-email-addresses.com" +
                ".just.kidding.this.domain.is.really.German.de";
        byte[] plainTextAsBytes = plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");

        byte[] encrypted = provider.encrypt(plaintext);
        String decrypted = provider.decrypt(encrypted);

        assertFalse(Arrays.equals(plainTextAsBytes, encrypted));
        assertEquals(plaintext, decrypted);
    }
}
```