# Using parameter in .xml file?

Tags: xml, spring, jasper-reports, jasperserver

In a .java file I can use "getProperty(PARAMETER_NAME)"

To get there value of a parameter

I have this block of code in a .xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ui.cas.ServiceProperties"
          id="authenticationServiceProperties">
        <property name="service">
            <value>http://v-repte-lnx.nwc.ac.za:8024/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_cas_security_check</value>
        </property>
        <property name="sendRenew">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

What I want to do is to not have the link (4th line) hardcoded

So the 4th line should look something like this

```
<value>getProperty(PARAMETER_NAME)</value>
```

**What can I use in this .xml file to achieve this ?**

EXTRA:

I am using *JasperReports Server 5.0.1*

My tree looks something like this

```
Webap>
  applicationContext-security.xml
  internal>
      jasperreports.properties
```

EDIT:

**I implemented user2550754's solution but can't get it to work**

See comment in user2550754's post

**UPDATE ON FILES NOW:**

applicationContext-security.xml file

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="../WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver-pro.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.ui.cas.ServiceProperties"
          id="authenticationServiceProperties">
        <property name="service">
            <value>${SERVICE_URL}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="sendRenew">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

jasperserver-pro.properties file

```
SERVICE_URL=http://b-reptes-lnx1.nuw.ac.za:8024/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_cas_security_check
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the dynamically a bean reference in Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124982/how-to-set-the-dynamically-a-bean-reference-in-spring)

Answer (score 2):

Store your configuration in a properties file, say `application.properties`

```
url=http://v-repte-lnx.nwc.ac.za:8024/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_cas_security_check
```

Then, add in your `.xml` as follows

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
</bean>
```

And configure your code like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ui.cas.ServiceProperties"
      id="authenticationServiceProperties">
    <property name="service">
        <value>${url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="sendRenew">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What should my value="classpath:application.properties"/> be ?
I tried value="classpath:internal\jasperserver-pro.properties"/> , No luck. I edited my post to show what the tree looks like

Comment: I have to replace <host:port> with the actual host & port, I can't do this because this puts me back at Square 1

Comment: try `value="classpath:internal/jasperreports.properties"`

Comment: In my case what will the absolute path be ? (the whole point of this is to make the code more generic (no hard-coded stuff))

Comment: I Just Tried it, sorry no luck

Comment: and `classpath:/internal/jasperproperties.properties`

Comment: I used value="../WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver-pro.properties" and got it to work now I get Could not resolve placeholder'SERVICE_URL' error

Comment: I added how my files look now see UPDATE ON FILES NOW:

Comment: change to `SERVICE_URL=http://b-reptes-lnx1.nuw.ac.za:8024/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_cas_security_check`

Comment: I did no luck same result (forgot to remove the ${} was just something I tried and hoped it would work)

Comment: Do all other properties from `jasperserver-pro.properties` are getting initialized?

Comment: Yes, They are used in .java files all throughout the project

Comment: ok so I changed value="classpath:jasperserver-pro.properties" to value="classpath:jaspersGGGGGGerver-pro.properties" and still get the same error, so I'm assuming its still not reading the file

Comment: try `value="classpath:/WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver-pro.properties"`

Comment: I've tried every single classpath known to man no luck, I don't think the problem is here. something else is causing the file not to be read

Comment: Ok, i have now tried using the same structure. Actually the `WEB-INF` is not in classpath. And we can provide only three parameters, which are `classpath, file and <url>`. Either you change location of your properties file or look out for some different thing instead of `properties` file.

Answer (score 2):

In last versions of Spring you can load properties in one line using `properties` tag from `util` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"> 

    <util:properties id="appProps" location="classpath:app.properties" />
```

and use them using `${key}` syntax in xml file:

```
<bean id="service" class="com.mycompany.Service">
    <property name="someParameter" value="${someParameterKey}"/>
</bean>
```

or in annotation:

```java
@Value("${someParameterKey}")
private String someParameter;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring property placeholder capability: 
1. externalize configuration file,
2. load with `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`
3. replace `<value>${x.y.z}</value>`