# Bean reference in Spring configuration file: which sintax?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Working for some time with Spring I often had to do with bean reference.

I've always used this syntax to refer to other beans in my application:

```
<ref bean="referenced_bean_id"/>
```

but sometimes, in third party applications, I see that the following sintax is also used:

```
<ref bean="${bean.referenced_bean_id}"/>
```

I haven't yet figured out what the difference is. Can you explain it?

Comment: isnt that what we call 'Dynamic bean referencing'?
using property place holder to configure which bean to use at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we call as "Dynamic bean referencing" , here we use property place holders so that at runtime we can decide which bean to use depending on other application parameters

for further reference you can have a look here

- http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/10377-dynamic-bean-reference

And a similar thread here ,

- [How to set dynamically a bean reference in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124982/how-to-set-dynamically-a-bean-reference-in-spring)
  Hope it helps!

Good luck!

Comment: so, the actual bean id is specified in a properties file, am I right?