# How to disable JMS spring listener in test evnvironment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jms, weblogic

I am using spring JMSTemplate to connect to a queue on a different weblogic domain.
I wired all the components like jndiTemplate, connectionfactory, destination etc in the Spring config. 
Messages are handled by a simple implementation of MessageListener.


It all works fine. But when I try to deploy this application where the destination is not available, deployment fails. this is very important for me as we dont have JMS infrastructure in some of our environments. 

I tried with lookupOnStartup=false on all the components and tried injecting them into DMLC based on a environment variable. But the issue is, the listener doesnt seem to be starting up. All the messages are left in the queue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Spring-config:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://wp2128.xyz.int:7001</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.authentication">none</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal"></prop>
            </props>    
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/connectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/testQueue" />
</bean>


<bean id="simpleConsumer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="simpleMessageListener" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You can use Spring profiles to remove the problematic bean in the test enviroment. http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/ See after "Enter bean definition profiles"

Comment: Here is another link that also refers what Evgeni menitioned using profiles for conditional startup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279270/is-there-any-way-to-enable-or-disable-the-spring-bean-definition-in-applicationc

Answer (score 1):

You can set autoStartup to false. This property value can be externalized in a properties files.

```
<bean id="simpleConsumer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="simpleMessageListener" />
   <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
</bean>
```